# Need help getting the graphics to work on a Hangman game

Tags: java, swing

I made a Hangman game and it's working, but I am having trouble incorporating the graphics for the game. I am trying to add a graphic every time you get a letter wrong, could someone give me ways on how to do this? I think the reason it's not working is because the method where the graphics is, is a void, but I am not sure how to fix this.

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.BoxLayout;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

public class Hangman extends JFrame {
    private String[] wordList = {"computer", "sport", "denver", "university", "education",
                    "action", "competiion", "mysterious", "program", "complete"};
    private JTextField inputField;
    private JLabel lettersUsed;
    static String letter;
    static int[] wordLength = new int[10];
    static int randomWord = (int) (Math.random() * 10);
    private JLabel lines;
    private int wrong = 0;
    private int right = 0;
    private Graphics2D g2d;
    private JPanel center = new JPanel();

    public Hangman() {
        setSize(500, 500);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setTitle("Hangman Game");

        JPanel bottomRight = new JPanel();
        JPanel bottomLeft = new JPanel();
        JPanel top = new JPanel();
        JPanel bottom = new JPanel();
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        add(panel);

        bottom.setLayout(new BoxLayout(bottom, BoxLayout.X_AXIS));
        panel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        panel.setOpaque(false);
        top.setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder(""));
        bottom.setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder(""));

        inputField = new JTextField(1);
        JLabel enterLetter = new JLabel("Enter a letter", JLabel.CENTER);
        lettersUsed = new JLabel("Letters used:  ", JLabel.CENTER);
        lines = new JLabel("__ ", JLabel.CENTER);

        top.add(enterLetter);
        top.add(inputField);
        bottomLeft.add(lettersUsed);
        bottomRight.add(lines);
        bottom.add(bottomLeft);
        bottom.add(bottomRight);
        panel.add(center, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        panel.add(top, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        panel.add(bottom, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

        HangmanListener hl = new HangmanListener();
        inputField.addActionListener(hl);

        String line = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            wordLength[i] = wordList[i].length();
        }
        int j = 0;
        while (j < wordLength[randomWord]) {
            line += "__ ";
            j++;
        }
        lines.setText(line);
    }

    private class HangmanListener implements ActionListener {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            JTextField inputField = (JTextField) e.getSource();
            letter = inputField.getText();
            inputField.setText("");
            lettersUsed.setText(lettersUsed.getText() + letter + " ");
            char[] labelText = lines.getText().toCharArray();
            char enteredChar = letter.charAt(0);

            if (!wordList[randomWord].contains(letter)) {
                wrong++;
                if (wrong == 1) {
                    System.out.println("1st mistake, 5 more tries");
                }
                if (wrong == 2) {
                    System.out.println("2st mistake, 4 more tries");
                }
                if (wrong == 3) {
                    System.out.println("3st mistake, 3 more tries");
                }
                if (wrong == 4) {
                    System.out.println("4st mistake, 2 more tries");
                }
                if (wrong == 5) {
                    System.out.println("5st mistake, 1 more tries");
                }
                if (wrong == 6) {
                    System.out.println("You Lose");
                    System.out.println("Your word was: " + wordList[randomWord]);

                }
                if (wrong > 6) {
                    System.out.println("You already lose!");
                }
                return;
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < wordList[randomWord].length(); i++) {
                if (wordList[randomWord].charAt(i) == enteredChar) {
                    labelText[3 * i] = ' ';
                    labelText[3 * i + 1] = enteredChar;
                    right++;
                }

                lines.setText(String.valueOf(labelText));
                if (labelText.length / 3 == right) {
                    System.out.println("You Win");
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        super.paint(g);
        g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
        g2d.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        g2d.drawLine(50, 450, 50, 100);
        g2d.drawLine(50, 100, 300, 100);
        g2d.drawLine(300, 100, 300, 150);

        /*
         * g.drawOval(275, 150, 50, 50);
         * g.drawLine(300, 200, 300, 300);
         * 
         * g.drawLine(300, 225, 250, 300);
         * g.drawLine(300, 225, 350, 300);
         * 
         * g.drawLine(300, 300, 250, 400);
         * g.drawLine(300, 300, 350, 400);
         * g.setFont(new Font("", Font.PLAIN, 20));
         * g.drawString("You Lose!", 250, 450);
         */
        if (!wordList[randomWord].contains(letter)) {
            if (wrong == 1) {
                g2d.drawOval(275, 150, 50, 50);
            }
            if (wrong == 2) {
                g2d.drawLine(300, 200, 300, 300);
            }
            if (wrong == 3) {
                g2d.drawLine(300, 225, 250, 300);
            }
            if (wrong == 4) {
                g2d.drawLine(300, 225, 350, 300);
            }
            if (wrong == 5) {
                g2d.drawLine(300, 300, 250, 400);
            }
            if (wrong == 6) {
                g2d.drawLine(300, 300, 350, 400);
                g2d.setFont(new Font("", Font.PLAIN, 20));
                g2d.drawString("You Lose!", 250, 450);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two problems in your code: First you have a refresh problem, add

```
Hangman.this.repaint();
```

before the return-Statement in line 117. Now the second problem becomes visible: In case of the e.g. 3rd error you have to draw not only one line, but the oval and two lines. But I guess you can fix this yourself. ;-)